# Why is my omniauth-github not working with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails app and I want to make a Github connect. I have followed the devise tutorial about Facebook and adapted it for Github.
I have this error on the callback, when accessing `/users/auth/github/callback?code=xxxxxxx`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users):
```

I know that other posts are related to this issue but their answer do not fix my problem.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def github
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Github") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.github_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
             :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:github]

      def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
          user.email = auth.info.email
          user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        end
      end

      def self.new_with_session(params, session)
        super.tap do |user|
          if data = session["devise.github_data"] && session["devise.github_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
            user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Are your files named correctly? This all looks fine, so I'm guessing it comes down to a file being in the wrong spot or named incorrectly.

Comment: I found a bit before you answered but you are 100% right, I put my user_controller in the test folder :). Thank you